# Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0 increases debug app size

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Upgrading *Android Gradle Plugin* from 3.5.0 to 3.6.0 is doubling our .aab debug files:

- Android Gradle Plugin **3.5.0**:

  - debug .aab: 98 MB
  - release .aab: 96 MB
- Android Gradle Plugin **3.6.0**:

  - debug .aab: 248 MB
  - release .aab: 96 MB

Any idea why this is happening or how to avoid it?

Thank you.

Comment: Any other changes to your build.gradle between the 2?

Comment: @spartygw None, just changing the Android Gradle Plugin version, I tried it several times.